# Inject global variable in a module

Tags: node.js

In nodejs, is there a way I can do this?

```
//require something here and inject in this module
//all the properties visible in that module ex:

require("color"); 
//inject directly making properties from 'color' module global to this module.

console.log(red);
//'red' variable here came from 'color' module
```

I don't know if this is already correct or I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to set explicitly each value you want to "import":

```
var color = require("color");

var red = color.red,
    green = color.green;

// …
```

Also, you could use `with` but it is widely not recommended :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with